# How to use mysql commands in lando environment?

Tags: linux, mysql, docker, drupal

I tried to test some different mysql commands in a script running in a lando container dedicated to a drupal installation. I run the setup as described in the [getting started guide](https://docs.lando.dev/drupal/getting-started.html). Everything is working fine except the mysql commands. When i log in the container via `lando ssh` and try to run a plain `mysql -u drupal9 -p` and type in my password i get a `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`. I tried `lando rebuild` and install `mysql-server`, which has no installation candidate, so i suspect i have to add some more information to the lando config because the classical way to perform a `lando mysql` is working, so i assume the Database is not reachable from within the lando drupal container. Here is the `lando info`. It loads the mysql config from within the hostsystem, not from the guest system. So thats the reason i suspect i have to change something in the config.

```
[ { service: 'appserver',
    urls:
     [ 'https://localhost:32835',
       'http://localhost:32836',
       'http://test.lndo.site:8000/',
       'https://test.lndo.site/' ],
    type: 'php',
    healthy: true,
    via: 'apache',
    webroot: 'web',
    config: { php: '/home/USER/.lando/config/drupal9/php.ini' },
    version: '8.0',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: true,
    hostnames: [ 'appserver.test.internal' ] },
  { service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '32834' },
    healthcheck: 'bash -c "[ -f /bitnami/mysql/.mysql_initialized ]"',
    creds: { database: 'drupal9', password: 'drupal9', user: 'drupal9' },
    config: { database: '/home/USER/.lando/config/drupal9/mysql.cnf' },
    version: '5.7',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: false,
    hostnames: [ 'database.test.internal' ] } ]
```

How can I use mysql commands within a lando environment inside the container after `lando ssh`?

EDIT I:

Here is the local .cnf file

```
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
# 0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

I also tried to install `mariadb-server` but the problem is still the same.